# Access SQL: select material with highest sum over a date range

Tags: ms-access

I have a form [called **history supplier tool**] where users can select a supplier from a list [called **list1**] and start/end dates. [called **list2** and **list 3** respectively]
Assume the user selects supplierX and start date 3/1/2016 and end date 6/1/2016. See picture of the dataset below.

I then want a query to pick the materialID offered by that supplier with the highest sum spend, within that specific time frame. In the example that would be materialID ABC222222222. The code below gives me the error "cannot have aggregate function in expression (max(sum([item master].spendpermaterial]). I'm a bit stuck as I thought aggregate functions were supposed to go in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT [Item Master].MaterialID, Max(Sum([Item Master].SpendPerMaterial)) AS Expr1
FROM [Item Master]
WHERE ((([Item Master].SupplierID)=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List1]) AND (([Item Master].DateStamp)>=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List2] And ([Item Master].DateStamp)<=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List3]))
GROUP BY [Item Master].MaterialID;
```

[image]

Comment: @HansUp I don't completely understand Hans. The example above is just a small example. The real database has suppliers with many different materials and many different datestamps.

Comment: If you are using ms.acces why  you have the tag mysql .. please remove the improper tag

Comment: @HansUp I see, but I don't see how I could get the output I want. I want the material with the most spend over the selected date range (hence sum), not tjust he material with the highest recorded spend (max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Item Master].MaterialID, Sum([Item Master].SpendPerMaterial) AS Amount
FROM [Item Master]
WHERE ((([Item Master].SupplierName)=[list1]) AND (([Item Master].DateStamp)>=[list2] And ([Item Master].DateStamp)<=[list3]))
GROUP BY [Item Master].MaterialID
ORDER BY Sum([Item Master].SpendPerMaterial) DESC;
```